# how to calculate complexity of a simple search

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

I have an array with n elements. Now I need to search an element x. Here is the program

```
int x[100],i,s;
cout<<"Enter how many number of element you have";
cin>>n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  cin>>x[i];
}
cout<<"Enter element which you want to search";
cin>>s;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  if(x[i]==s)
  {
   cout<<"Item found in position"<<i;
   break;
  }
}
```

what's the time and space complexity of this program?

```
Space: 
x[100] = 200 bytes
n      = 1 byte 
s      = 1 byte
==================
Total  = 202 bytes
```

is it correct?

Time Complexity:
Please help me to figure out

Best case scenario(if x matches first element of n) complexity?
Worst case scenario(if x matches last element of n or doesn't match) complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity:

```
Time complexity is nothing but number of comparisons done by computer in your code.
```

So, when you search your array you actually do n comparisons. Comparing each element in the array with your input element. So, in this case:

Best case: O(1) - Element is found in the first comparison.

Worst case: O(n) - Means you had to search through all the elements and you found the element at the last place of the array.

Space complexity:

```
Normally, this is seen in terms of numbers of elements in the array rather 
then the total size taken by these elements. This is done because size of data 
types differ on various architectures but number of elements is dependent on the 
problem and not the machine.
```

Hence, in your case:

Space complexity = "n"..Since n elements are present in the array.